# Why is react component getting too many re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am not new to react, but for some reason I feel like it.

My react component is re-rendering infinitely:

```js
  const [apiDetails, setApiDetails] = useState({});
  const { onboardApi, fetchOneApi } = useActions();

  // get apiDetails from the redux store
  const { apiList } = useSelector((state) => state.marketplace);
  console.log('api list', apiList);

  /* 
   * if I move this block inside useEffect's if condition, 
   * it fixes it but the state is not getting changed 
   */
  if (apiList && apiList[apiId]) {
    setApiDetails((oldState) => ({ ...oldState, ...apiList[apiId] })); 
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch the api details to show dropdown options
    if (!implementation) {
      fetchOneApi(apiId);
    }
  }, [implementation]);
```

`apiDetails` is further passed to a child component.

`implemention` is coming from the router:

```js
<Route
    path="/implementation/:id"
    exact
    render={(props) => <OnboardPage {...props} implementation={true} />}
/>
```

Comment: What is `implementation`?

Comment: it is a prop sent from the router, this component has two use cases coming from different routes. Its nothing but a boolean value. Depending on its value, this comopnent has different behaviour

Comment: What about `apiId`? Is it also a prop?

Comment: coming from param (url)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (apiList && apiList?[apiId]) {
    setApiDetails((oldState) => ({ ...oldState, ...apiList[apiId] })); 
  }
```

The problem lies in the above bit of your code.

Each time the component renders, the if block runs and updates state. When state updates the component renders again. And the if runs again, another state change, another render. Therefore, your infinite renders. Move it into a separate useEffect from the one you are already using.

Never set state in the main function body of the component, wrap it in another nested function and call that function from one or more event handlers (`onClick or onChange`) as per requirement or place them in the [recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (apiList?.[apiId]) {
      setApiDetails((oldState) => ({ ...oldState, ...apiList[apiId] })); 
    }
}, [apiId])
```

You can verify the said behavior with your current implementation by simply not passing the query param `apiId`, in which case the if statement will not run and your component state will not update. So, no additional renders, no infinite loop.

Also, you can just pass an empty array `[]` as the second parameter to useEffect instead of `[apiId]` because apiId is extracted from query params as per your comments. So, it is either defined or undefined when the component renders and its not likely to change during the lifetime of your component. `[]` **guarantees** that the if statement will run only once, immediately after the component mounts.

Finally, if your setup supports ES2020 try out [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), it's very handy for null checks. You will write lesser code.